Unity Shader graph. Проблема с Sample Texture 2D
Хотела для объекта сделать простой эффект свечение с помощью шейдера, но при добавление спрайта в Sample Texture 2D его отображает как указано на картинке, как убрать задний фон что оно добавляет?:

Так же если это нужно или как-то поможет добавляю настройки самого спрайта:


